# How to cleanly edit sshd_config for basic security options in an ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to write a playbook that cleanly edits /etc/ssh/sshd_config so that it has `PasswordAuthentication no` and `PermitRootLogin no`.

I can think of a few ways that are all problematic.

Firstly, I could delete all the lines matching `PasswordAuthentication|PermitRootLogin` using lineinfile, and then append two new lines that I want, but i) this can fail non-atomically AND ii) appending lines at the end can mix them up with 'Match' blocks, which can typically appear at the end.

I could replace every line matching `^(# *)?PasswordAuthentication` with `PasswordAuthentication no`, also using lineinfile, but that doesn't work if a matching line doesn't already exist. Also, if there are multiple matching lines, I'll have duplicate `PasswordAuthentication no` lines.

I could use a template for the entire file, but that means I need to specify everything, including HostKey, but I don't want to specify everything and want to leave the other options the way they were originally setup.

None of the above ways are satisfactory because of the problems listed. Is there a clean way that makes the desired changes reliably, is idempotent, and does not leave the system in a bad state if it fails halfway?

Comment: What's your question? Do you expect us to make the choice for you?

Comment: The question is in the title, now clarified in the last paragraph.

Answer (score 17):

This solution requires only one task and no additional files:

```
- name: Configure sshd
  lineinfile:
    path: "/etc/ssh/sshd_config"
    regex: "^(#)?{{item.key}}"
    line: "{{item.key}} {{item.value}}"
    state: present
  loop:
    - { key: "PermitRootLogin", value: "no" }
    - { key: "PasswordAuthentication", value: "no" } 
  notify:
    - restart sshd
```

As pointed out in the comments, this solution is risky, as it requires a regex match. Without a match, a new line is generated at the end of the file which can conflict with match sections in the `sshd_config` file.

Comment: lineinfile will putt the line at the end if its not there, and as mentioned this can mess up configuration...

Answer (score 8):

> I could replace every line matching ^(# *)?PasswordAuthentication with PasswordAuthentication no, also using lineinfile, but that doesn't work if a matching line doesn't already exist. Also, if there are multiple matching lines, I'll have duplicate PasswordAuthentication no lines.

You just did not get/test how `lineinfile` is effectively working as this is exactly the solution you are looking for. In your particular case, without a backreference, the module will:

- Look if the line you want to add is effectively there in which case it will do nothing
- If the line does not exist, look for the regex to match it
- If one or several match are found, the last occurrence will be replaced by the given line
- If no regex is found, the line will be added at the end of the file
- If you still need to add the line in a particular place in the file if it does not exists, you can use `insertbefore` or `insertafter`

See the following example:

initial `test.config` with multiple matching lines:

```ini
# PasswordAuthentication no
# PermitRootLogin no
somevalue no
# PasswordAuthentication no
# PermitRootLogin no
othervalue yes
# PasswordAuthentication no
# PermitRootLogin no
```

and `test2.config` with no match

```ini
value none
othervalue no
yetanother yes
```

The test playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: Line in file test
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: test replace
      lineinfile:
        path: "{{ item }}"
        regex: ^(# *)?PasswordAuthentication
        line: PasswordAuthentication no
      loop:
        - /path/to/test.config
        - /path/to/test2.config
```

Running the playbook changes the files on first run and reports ok on subsequent runs (no more changes being made). Here are the files once modified by the module.

`test.config`:

```ini
# PasswordAuthentication no
# PermitRootLogin no
somevalue no
# PasswordAuthentication no
# PermitRootLogin no
othervalue yes
PasswordAuthentication no
# PermitRootLogin no
```

and `test2.config`

```ini
value none
othervalue no
yetanother yes
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Comment: Yes, I had a misunderstanding of lineinfile, which I thank you for pointing out, but the problem still exists. If the original file has two lines, `PasswordAuthentication yes` followed by `#PasswordAuthentication no`, after applying the lineinfile, there will be two lines, `PasswordAuthentication yes` followed by `PasswordAuthentication no`, which is bad. Matching `^ *PasswordAuthentication` instead helps in this case, but in the case where there is no `PasswordAuthentication yes`, a new line `PasswordAuthentication yes` gets appended at the end where it can inadvertently join a match block.

Comment: You would then have to check for the absence of `PasswordAuthentiction yes` prior to applying your rules. From experience, automating your infra and letting users connect directly and screw-up the configs however they want while keeping their changes rarely gets along. Make a template starting wi'th "{{ ansible_managed }}", letting the user know their changes will be lost next time you pass by. They can try something on their own and ask you to integrate it to your template if it needs to be kept.

Comment: Had to update the regex like so `^(#  *)?PermitRootLogin (yes|no)` because lineinfile find and replace the _PasswordAuthentication_ line in the PAM comment section (line 75).

Comment: `lineinfile` seems to be unfitted to edit this configuration file. There are 27 config lines that could be both on "general" configuration and/or on `match` blocks. Deleting duplicates is not desirable. Default behaviour for this module would only edit config on the last `match` and leave the rest in their current values. Appending by default is scary as it could break working configurations (I've seen it several times already). It's pretty strange that the only service ansible relies on does not have a proper way to edit its configuration without templates or knowing the exact content...

Comment: @NuTTyX One option is to do a pre-pass to remove lines such that each configuration directive has at most one occurrence, uncommented or commented.

Answer (score 6):

I think you could work with `lineinfile` and use `state=absent` and `state=present` like this:

```
- name: deactivate PermitRootLogin
  lineinfile:
    path: "/etc/ssh/sshd_config"
    line: "PermitRootLogin no"
    state: present
  notify:
    - restart sshd

- name: ensure PermitRootLogin is not activated
  lineinfile:
    path: "/etc/ssh/sshd_config"
    line: "PermitRootLogin yes"
    state: absent
  notify:
    - restart sshd
```

Same would work for `PasswordAuthentication yes/no`.

Answer (score 3):

If *template* is not an option then *lineinfile* shall be used. To address the details:

> .. append two new lines that I want, but i) this can fail non-atomically ...

If it fails to complete, fix it and repeat the play.

> ...  if there are multiple matching lines, I'll have duplicate PasswordAuthentication no lines.

Validate the configuration and if it fails to complete fix it and repeat the play.

```
validate: "{{ sshd_path }} -t -f %s"
```

> None of the above ways are satisfactory ...

Such an expectation is not realistic. Both problems (arbitrary fail, matching lines) describe the erroneous states that do not have to be necessarily resolved by the module. *lineinfile* fits the purpose completely. For example, see [sshd.yml](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-linux-postinstall/blob/master/tasks/sshd.yml).

Answer (score 3):

One alternative and more elegant option to editing the file line by line is to completely replace the */etc/ssh/sshd_config* file with a new copy.

This is the approach suggested in the [RedHat Ansible security hardening guide](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/harden-new-system-ansible). It has the significant benefit that it guarantees defined behaviour, as the chance of unanticipated edge cases is significantly reduced (as could happen with regex pattern replacement on a pre-exisiting file). It also means you can ensure consistency across your server fleet and makes it easier to tidy up / improve config in the future, as need arises.

Suggested sshd_config file:

```
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials no
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding no
Banner /etc/issue.net
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
PermitRootLogin no
```

Ansible YAML to copy over sshd_config:

```
- name: Add hardened SSH config
  copy:
    dest: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    src: etc/ssh/sshd_config
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0600
  notify: Reload SSH
```

Ansible YAML to restart SSH:

```
handlers:
  - name: Reload SSH
    service:
      name: sshd
      state: reloaded
```

Answer (score 3):

Your distribution's default sshd config `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` may have an include directive:

```
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d
```

Ideally this is at the start of the config as the sshd_config manpage suggests that the first value (per option) wins: `for each keyword, the first obtained value will be used`. This appears to be the case for Ubuntu and Fedora as of this writing.

This allows us to put our desired config into a file we control with a task such as:

```yaml
- name: explicitly configure password authentication=no
  become: yes
  lineinfile:
    path: "/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/00-user.conf"
    line: "PasswordAuthentication no"
    state: present
    create: true
  notify: restart sshd
```

This alone may be enough to ensure our config always wins as files are processed in lexical order (see [sshd_config(5)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sshd_config.5.html)).

However to be extra sure we can remove any contradictory config from other config files:

```yaml
- name: find all sshd configs
  become: yes
  ansible.builtin.find:
    paths: "/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d"
    file_type: file
    use_regex: true
    recurse: yes
  register: sshd_configs
- name: remove password authentication=yes if present
  become: yes
  lineinfile:
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
    # Ignore any commented lines, don't change more than we need to
    # (?i) case insensitive match, ^(?!#) negative lookahead - line must not start with #
    regex: "(?i)^(?!#).*PasswordAuthentication.*yes"
    state: absent
  loop: "{{ sshd_configs.files + [{'path': '/etc/ssh/sshd_config'}] }}"
  notify: restart sshd
```

Comment: The sshd_config manpage suggests that the first value (per option) wins: `For each keyword, the first obtained value will be used.` This would suggest that with your approach, it would be better to use a `00-user.conf` instead of a `99-user.conf` - to have the customized default-values applied as early as possible. And the include-line should be at the start of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, for the same reason (which it also is by default, at least on Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04). If that's the case, IMO it's a nice and easy way to put defaults into place properly.

Comment: Thanks @weiresr - I've updated the filename and taken your quote on first values winning also.